# Facing an Error when installing create-react-app package from npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to install React on my Computer. I'm a beginner and installing it for the first time. However, when I used `create-react-app react-app` to start a project, it showed the following: [image]

But the app is working fine, I launched the server through `npm start` and it works, so should I ignore these errors or not?

Answer (score 0):

the first warning you get (`deprecated`) means that one of the packages you are using (in this case - `source-map-resolve`) was deprecated (i.e is not maintained). you can go to the package [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated) to find a way to resolve it.

the second error you get (cannot read properties of undefined) tells you that there is a difference between versions of global packages. sometimes restarting your wifi helps it, or updating NPM/windows/node/all your packages

Answer (score 0):

run `npm audit fix` and see if that helps. If not then i would just continue working on your project. Since you're a beginner you will learn more about NPM as you work. Npm is notorious for installing a ton of dependencies that are deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I've started working on it and everything seems just fine to me. So, I should ignore it right? Or should I try to run that command first?

Comment: run the command, it wont do any damage.